# setState returns undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I dont know if it is right or not but I did this with my `useState` to having multiple states but now I'm getting undefined instead of switching between true and false.
How can I fix this

```
let [Click,setClick] = useState({button1:false,button2:false})

const changeItem = () =>{
setClick(!Click.button1)
console.log(Click.button1)
}
```

This function applied on a Button component's onclick event
First I'm getting `false` then `undefined`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## What is happening

The initial state is:

```
{button1:false,button2:false}
```

Then (via `changeItem`) you call `setClick(!Click.button1)` which sets a new state (`false` because `!any_object` is `false`).

Then you call `console.log(Click.button1)` which logs `false` because the initial state's `button1` property is `false`.

Then a re-render is triggered which creates a new `Click` variable containing the new state and a new `changeItem` function which closes over the new `Click` variable.

Next time you call `changeItem` again and:

```
setClick(!Click.button1)
```

`Click` is `false` so `Click.button1` is `undefined` so you set the state to `true`.

Then `console.log(Click.button1)`  logs the previously closed over `Click`'s (`false`) `button1` property which is `undefined` because booleans don't have those properties.

## How to update a property of an object in the state

You need to assign a new **object** to the state in which you only change the value you care about:

```
setState({
    ...Click, // Shallow copy all the old values
    button1: !Click.button1, // Change the one you care about
})
```

## How to observe the change

Use a `useEffect` hook to log the value **when the state changes**:

```
useEffect( () => { console.log(Click); }, [Click] )
```

---

## A note about style

By convention, variable names starting with capital letters are reserved for constructor functions and classes. Don't use them to store data. Call it `click`.

Answer (score 0):

State updates in React do not reflect immediately.

You can read more about it here:
[useState set method not reflecting change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately/54069332#54069332)

Also, with useState hook, updates aren't merged and hence you have to update the complete object

You can use the callback approach to update the state like below

```
let [Click,setClick] = useState({button1:false,button2:false})

const changeItem = () =>{
   setClick(prev=> ({...prev, button1: !prev.button1}))
}  

// you can see the updated state here in the next render cycle
console.log(Click.button1);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that in `changeItem` you're calling `setClick(!Click.button1)` which is resetting your entire `Click` state variable.

If you you're trying to change the state to be `{button1: true, button2: false}`, then you can use the spread operator to copy your state and then modify only the value of `button1`

```
const changeItem = () => {
  setClick({ ...Click, button1: !Click.button1 });
}
```

This should do it.